# How can I identify which face of an OpenGL ES cube has been touched?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

Using OpenGL ES, I have created a cube with textures. I am now looking to make each textured  side tappable, so I can create a cube which navigates to a different views on touching particular sides.

How can I implement this?

In addition, how can I know which sides of the cube are currently visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common 3d graphics task, used in games that use the mouse.  You need to calculate the X and Y position on the screen where you touch, create a ray starting at that position (with Z = 0) and going to Z = infinity, then convert that ray into world space (from camera space).  Then use that ray to calculate which triangle it intersects first.

Google search "ray triangle intersection" for the maths and algorithms for this.  For a simple cube you can just iterate through all your triangles.  For more complex scenes you will need to spatially hash your triangles (using octtrees, bsps etc) to make it more performant.

Answer (score 2):

There are different techniques to perform the selection of an object or, like in your case, a face of an object in OpenGL.

There is the ray intersection technique which I find an overkill for your case though as cthutu said, it is a viable solution.

The solution I would suggest to you anyway is the color picking technique.

It consists in rendering the objects or the faces of an object in a backbuffer in a pre-determined color when the user "clicks" on the screen. The rendering is done into a texture and the job is to read the color of the pixel where the user clicked.

Once you have the color of the pixel, you can easily determine which object or face was clicked.

For instance, let me say you have a cube with 6 faces, you assign a color to each face (i.e. red, blue, yellow, orange, green, white) and you store the assigned color somewhere in your program's logic. When the user clicks, you render the cube with these fake colors, you read the color and then you render again on  the screen with the actual colors/textures. At the end of the process, you check the color of the pixel, for instance yellow, and from there you determine the selection.

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: There will be extra complication if any lights are involved since the shade of red will vary if the cube rotates.  But it should be still possible if you stick to primary and secondary colours of which you have six: red, blue, green, magenta, cyan, yellow.

Comment: Actually in the picking frame it is a common practice to use a different shared where lighting in not kept into consideration and a flat rendering is applied.